# How to control meteorjs authentication based on geolocation?

Tags: geolocation, meteor

I want to force users to enable their geolocation, otherwise disallow login to meteor site.

I am using accounts-ui, and {{loginButtons}} in a handlebars template called "login".

```
login.html
<template name="login">
  {{loginButtons}}
</template>

login.js
Template.login.rendered = function() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
  } else {
    Meteor.logout();
  }
}
```

I get the prompt for geolocation (using chrome), but when I click deny, it still lets me log in. Would it be better to check for geolocation on meteor startup prior to even using the site? Ideally, I'm looking for a way to check for geolocation when Meteor.isLoggingIn().

Comment: Do you mean to log the user out if `.getCurrentPosition` returns an error?  Currently logout will only get called if the browser does not support geolocation.  Some examples of geolocation use [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation_error)

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'd rather not log user out after they login, if I can do it "while" they are logging in. Template.login.rendered tells me the user is already logged in, so maybe I need to add the geolocation to Deps.autorun and check for Meteor.loggingin there? I see that accounts-ui-unstyled is using this logic in handlebars - http://goo.gl/p2XGB7 - so *idea* maybe the way to check for geolocation prior is {{#if logginin}} {{> checkForGeolocation}} {{loginButtons}}{{/if}}?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to avoid showing the login buttons at all unless there is a geocode.

login.html

```
<template name="login">
  {{#if showLogin}}
    {{loginButtons}}
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

login.js

```
Template.login.helpers({
  showLogin: function () {
    successCallback = function (loc) { Session.set('curLocation', loc);}
    errorCallback = function (err) { 
      Session.set('curLocation', null);
      if (Meteor.userId()) {
        Meteor.logout();
      }
    }

    // This just checks to see if the browser supports geolocation. 
    if (navigator.geolocation){
      // Actually checks for geocode.
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback);
    }

    // Tricky bit:  Reactive variable changes (and reruns) when callback changes.
    //              Since the variable is only set on success, this function will 
    //              only ever be true on a success.
    return Session.get('curLocation');
  }
});
```